# Error during Azure service bus binding with azure function

Tags: azure, function, azureservicebus

I am getting below error when trying to do output binding of azure service bus with azure function V1.
Please assist.
I have given correct keys. Still I am getting this error while trying to run on local

`System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.docschunkingwithservicebus. Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus: The queue or topic name provided does not match the EntityPath in the connection string passed to the ServiceBusClient constructor.`

Please assist me on same

Comment: What is the runtime stack of your function? Also please provide your code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This indicates that your connection string has an "EntityPath" slug that identifies one queue/topic and the parameters that you're using to configure your Function reference a queue/topic that is different than what is in your connection string.

I'd suggest removing the "EntityPath" slug and value from the connection string or use the Azure portal to copy the connection string from the Service Bus namespace rather than a specific entity.